# How to call the storedprocedure using simplejdbc call with annotation mapping in spring application?

Tags: spring-boot

I have the spring rest apllication in java 11 where i have to call postgreSql storedprocedure and process the result.so decide to go with simplejdbccall template but not sure if we can use this with @annotation mapping. please suggest how to do this?

Comment: What did you try so far? Have you read a tutorial like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/springjdbc/springjdbc_simplejdbccall.htm

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, I read this, It has Xml based mapping , not annotation based.  Can I use annotation based mapping in the same code instead of creating XML.

Comment: That's not XML based mapping thats Spring with XML but you can use it with annotations. But if you really need to access a lot of procedures you better use https://www.jooq.org/